Why is the lubridate package returning invalid time zone error?
I recently updated to R version 4.4 and lubridate version 1.9.3 and started getting this error below when I try to add a period of time to a posixct variable.

Error in C_time_add(time, periods, roll_month, roll_dst) : CCTZ: Invalid timezone of the input vector: ""

A google search showed that this was a problem in an earlier version of lubridate, but was fixed. Does anyone have any insight into how it can be resolved? For small time intervals I can calculate and add the number of seconds elapsed, but that's a problem if I want to add months or years to the date. Any comments are appreciated! Thanks
as.POSIXct("2024-5-23")+ days(1)

Error in C_time_add(time, periods, roll_month, roll_dst) : 
  CCTZ: Invalid timezone of the input vector: ""

It works as expected if I use as.Date
as.Date("2024-5-23")+ days(1)
[1] "2024-05-24"

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.9.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] vctrs_0.6.5       generics_0.1.3    tools_4.4.0       compiler_4.4.0    cli_3.6.2         timechange_0.3.0  rlang_1.1.3       glue_1.7.0        rstudioapi_0.16.0

> as.POSIXct("2024-5-23")+ days(1)
Error in C_time_add(time, periods, roll_month, roll_dst) : 
  CCTZ: Invalid timezone of the input vector: ""


as.POSIXct("2024-5-23") + days(1) works fine with lubridate 1.9.3

I agree with @AndreWildberg.  Do you get the same error with as.POSIXct("2024-5-23")+ lubridate::days(1)?  If not, that suggests a namespace conflict.

@AndreWildberg, Thank you for that suggestion. I get the same error as before

as.POSIXct("2024-05-24") + lubridate::days(1)
Error in C_time_add(time, periods, roll_month, roll_dst) :
CCTZ: Invalid timezone of the input vector: ""
packageDescription("lubridate")
Type: Package
Package: lubridate
Title: Make Dealing with Dates a Little Easier
Version: 1.9.3


sorry about the clunkiness in the reply, first post- I'm figuring out how this works. @Ben Bolker, my mistake in the first post. The lubridate version is 1.9.3, the currently available one on CRAN

In this case try as.POSIXct("2024-5-23") + as.period(1, unit="days") or ymd("2024-5-23") + 1

The ymd option and as.Date options work, but posixct still fails


as.POSIXct("2024-5-23") + as.period(1, unit="days")
Error in C_time_add(time, periods, roll_month, roll_dst) :
CCTZ: Invalid timezone of the input vector: ""
ymd("2024-5-23") + as.period(1, unit="days")
[1] "2024-05-24"
as.Date("2024-5-23") + as.period(1, unit="days")
[1] "2024-05-24"


The comments here suggest that you may have a package that was built under a previous version of R. Try update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE) ?

Thanks for taking the time to look though this, @Ben Bolker. I unloaded other packages, loaded the lubridate library and ran again. Same error. Edited the original post to reflect changes

I was encountering this same issue just now with R 4.3.2 and lubridate 1.9.3 on Windows 10. I reinstalled lubridate which didn't help, but then updated ALL packages and that seems to have resolved the issue for me.
